# Event Queue Created Field (time stamp)

Tags: publishing, event-queue

I noticed today after I published that the times being put into the created field of the event queue happened to be dates from the future. All the servers CM, CD, DB, QA are PST. I set the time zone value to

```
   <setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="400" />
```

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx).

This could be related to my CD indexes not updating correctly. Any thoughts on making the time match with the server? I adjusted the timezone value in the web.config and republished and it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

I found out that field is populated with UTC regardless of what the server time zone is.